# Import flutter web app inside Reactjs application iframe

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flutter, iframe, hosting

I have a React app, written in typescript.
I want to open/show a flutter web app inside an iframe, without needing another server to host the flutter app.

Basically I have the build/web code from the flutter app, and when I start my react application (using npm start), I want it to also host the flutter app. This works, for some extent, however:

Putting the build/web folder from flutter inside the public folder of the React app does indeed host the files, however, I can't open the build/web/index.html in an iframe, because it throws an error on the console:
[image]

by checking the source, surprisingly the flutter.js got overwritten by the react html [image]

**so my question is how can I host the flutter web app along with the react app, and then use the flutter app inside an iframe?**